# tkinter grow frame to fit content

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, kde-plasma

I am trying to resize the tk-window dynamically to its contents.

So I thought after 2 seconds the tk-window should display the long Text. 
But what i get is that after 2 seconds the window gets large enough on the X-Axis, but only a little bit larger on the Y-Axis. I see just the letter 'a' instead of the full text.

I tried messing around with expand and fill, but the window size wont't change.
Can somebody point out why the window-size won't adapt the label size?
I am running Python 3.5.3 on Kubuntu 17.0.4 using tk 8.6.6

[image: before]
[image: after]

```
import tkinter as tk

def doIt():
    label.configure(text="text\na\n\n\n This is very long")

root = tk.Tk()
label=tk.Label(root,text="before")
label.pack()
root.after(2000,doIt)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code it grows as I would expect. Are you manually resizing the window before it updates?

Comment: No, no resizes before the update. Maybe just something wrong in the environment? What OS are are you running?

Comment: Your code, as is, works fine on Win10 with 3.5.4.

Comment: Works fine on Mac OS

Comment: Works as expected in Windows 7 , python 3.6.0. I'd consider uploading an image of the two GUIs for better validation.

Comment: Try manually doing `root.update()` right after you call `.configure()`

Comment: `root.update()` didn't change the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a problem/inconsitency in the Kubuntu environment. I created a
[bugreport](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/4e5c27418a5a2441baac34946f3100ff4bb2820c) on the tk ticketsystem.
As a workaround you can use the following code (Ethan was close):

```
import tkinter as tk

def doIt():
    label.configure(text="text\na\n\n\n This is very long")

root = tk.Tk()
root.update() # This is the workaround
label=tk.Label(root,text="before")
label.pack()
root.after(2000,doIt)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried messing around with expand and fill, but the window size
>   wont't change.

I have no idea how you did that, however setting those two options to the right values will give you the result you expect:

```
import tkinter as tk

def doIt():
    label.configure(text="text\na\n\n\n This is very long")

root = tk.Tk()
label=tk.Label(root,text="before")
label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) # I changed this
root.after(2000,doIt)
root.mainloop()
```

Output (after 2 seconds):

[image]

Now let us test with a longer text:

```
def doIt():
    label.configure(text="text\na\n\n\n This is very long This is very long This is very long \n\n\nThis is very long This is very long")
```

Output after 2 seconds:

[image]

Comment: i ran your code, i am still getting exactly the same behavior